# Place object in scene, SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, swift

File GameScene have class GameScene, class GameScene have CirclePhysicsDefault:

```
func circlePhysicsDefault() {
var Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
Circle.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
Circle.name = "defaultCircle"
Circle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
Circle.glowWidth = 10.0
Circle.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
Circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
Circle.physicsBody.dynamic = true
self.addChild(Circle)
}
```

In file GameViewController i type:

```
@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
GameScene().circlePhysicsDefault()
}
```

I linked this to button.

Run application, push the button - nothing happens.

If in GameScene function didMoveToView i call function circlePhysicsDefault, then app launch circle will be placed.

File GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

/* Pick a size for the scene */
let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
// Configure the view.
let skView = self.view as SKView
skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true

/* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

/* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

skView.presentScene(scene)
}

@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene").circlePhysicsDefault()
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.toRaw())
} else {
return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.toRaw())
}
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}




override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
return false }
}
```

File GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        circlePhysicsDefault()
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }

    func sceneSetting() {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.grayColor()
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.01, -2)
        }
    func circlePhysicsDefault() {
        var Circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
        Circle.position = CGPointMake(500, 500)
        Circle.name = "defaultCircle"
        Circle.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        Circle.glowWidth = 10.0
        Circle.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
        Circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        Circle.physicsBody.dynamic = true
        self.addChild(Circle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method of pressing the button:

```
@IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene").circlePhysicsDefault()
}
```

does not do anything with the scene you created earlier. Method `circlePhysicsDefault()` called from another GameScene class object. Thats why there is no object on you scene. To fix this problem you can store the pointer to you scen object and call methods using it.

Your GameViewController in this case will look like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var myScene: GameScene?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")

        self.myScene = scene

        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    @IBAction func addOneCircle(sender: AnyObject) {
        if self.myScene != nil {
            self.myScene!.circlePhysicsDefault()
        }
    }
.......
.......
.......
}
```